# Positioning tabs in TabContainer

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, tabcontainer

I'm working with `ajaxtoolkit:TabContainer`.

I need to add two tabs (which i can do) but i need one of the tab headers in the far left and the other in the far right.

I've been playing with CSS (`float:left; etc;`) but i can't separate them! They always show themselves glued together one after the other.

Is it possible to separate the tab headers?

**EDIT:**

As @1stein commented i could use

```
.ajax__tab_header :nth-child(2) { float: right !important; }
```

and that will do the trick. The problem is, this solution does not work in IE8 which is the browser i'm targeting. Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: Have you tried changing the order of the tabpanels in the html view? see [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1186178/2034285.aspx).

Comment: @Marijn i have no problems with order, i just want the tab headers to separate apart. they always render glued together. thanks for your time :)

Comment: [Here](http://www.krissteele.net/blogdetails.aspx?id=117) are some tips for the TabContainer and CSS.

Comment: You may use this style:
    .ajax__tab_header :nth-child(2)
    {
        float: right !important;
    } The only problem that it doesn't works in IE below 9th version. Or you can use style on the page by element id for the specific tab, but this not universal solition.

Comment: @1stein that's exactly what i need, but i need it to work in ie8.. is there some workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this style (doesn't works in IE below 9th version):

```
.ajax__tab_header :nth-child(2)
{
    float: right !important;
}
```

Or you can apply style via javascript (right below the ScriptManager):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);

    function pageLoaded(sender, args) {
        $get("<%= TabPanel2.ClientID %>_tab").setAttribute("style", "float:right");
    }
</script>
```

Where the TabPanel2 is ID of TabPanel which you need to move right.

Answer (score 0):

=D [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/)

Check out this js library... it will fix your css selector issue